# Java XML Read with WSIL file

Tags: java, xml, jsoup

at the moment I am trying to program a program which is able to render a link of an xml-file. I use Jsoup, my current code is the following

```
 public static String XmlReader() {
    InputStream is = RestService.getInstance().getWsilFile();
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(fis, null, "", Parser.xmlParser());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

I would like to read the following part from a XML file:

```
<wsil:service>
        <wsil:abstract>Read the full documentation on: https://host/sap/bc/mdrs/cdo?type=psm_isi_r&amp;objname=II_QUERY_PROJECT_IN&amp;saml2=disabled</wsil:abstract>
        <wsil:name>Query Projects</wsil:name>
        <wsil:description location="host/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/srvc_00163E5E1FED1EE897C188AB4A5723EF/wsdl11/allinone/ws_policy/document?sap-vhost=host&amp;saml2=disabled" referencedNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>
    </wsil:service>
```

I want to return the following URL as String

```
host/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/srvc_00163E5E1FED1EE897C188AB4A5723EF/wsdl11/allinone/ws_policy/document?sap-vhost=host&amp;saml2=disabled
```

How can I do that ?

Thank you

Comment: doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml);
  System.out.println(doc.select("wsil|description").attr("location"));

Comment: Thank you, I still have a question, how can I have this from a certain selection, as here is the <wsil: name> Query Projects </ wsil: name> but now there are others with <wsil: name> ... </ wsil: name> in the XML file, how do I get it filtered?

Comment: System.out.println(doc.select("wsil|name:contains(Query Projects)").first().parent().select("wsil|description").attr("location"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is only one tag `wsil:description` then you can use this code:

```
doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml);
String val = doc.select("wsil|description").attr("location");
```

Escape mode should be changed, since you are not working on regular html, but xml.

If you have more than one tag with given name you can search for distinct neighbour element, and find required tag with respect to it:

```
String val = doc.select("wsil|name:contains(Query Projects)").first().parent().select("wsil|description").attr("location");
```